# Flex: ArrayCollection of a Dto

Tags: arrays, apache-flex

I have a result which I map into an ArrayCollection (default Objects), but I need that ArrayCollection to be composed of a Specific Dto (CarsDto). How Can I do this?

The one working:

```
provincesList = inProvince.dataProvider as ArrayCollection;
```

I need that this ArrayCollection has to be composed of this Dto (CarsDto) but I don't know how to do this. I tried this but there is an error.

```
provincesList = inProvince.dataProvider as CarsDto:ArrayCollection;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using AMF with BlazeDS you have to instantiate the CarsDTO class one time before using the service, to tell the deserializer to use this class.